# Julia : How to convert vector of type string to type numeric (Float64)

Tags: string, vector, type-conversion, character, julia

In `Julia 1.1` I want to convert a vector of type string to type numeric (Float64)
here is the vector:

```
string = ["2.2", "3,3", "4.4"];
```

I tried the following line without success:

```
x = convert(Float64, string)
x = convert(DataVector{Float64}, string)
x = map(x->parse(Float64,x),string)
x = parse(Float64,string)
x = Float64(string)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest is:

```
julia> s = ["2.2", "3.3", "4.4"];

julia> parse.(Float64, s)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.2
 3.3
 4.4
```

but `map` will also work:

```
julia> map(x->parse(Float64,x), s)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.2
 3.3
 4.4
```

The problem in your original example is twofold:

- the second string `"3,3"` is an invalid `Floa64` number (it has a wrong decimal delimiter);
- while valid, I would recommend you not to use `string` as a name for a variable as it will overshadow `string` function from Base.

Additionally if your original strings have comma as a decimal delimiter then you can run `replace` on them first, e.g. here I broadcast it over a vector:

```
julia> s = ["2.2", "3,3", "4,4"];

julia> replace.(s, [','=>'.'])
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "2.2"
 "3.3"
 "4.4"
```

*EDIT*: as indicated by [DNF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2749865/dnf) it is actually a bit faster to write eiter:

```
replace.(s, (','=>'.',))
```

or

```
replace.(s, Ref(','=>'.'))
```

The general rule is that you are doing broadcasting because you have used a `.` so all your arguments should be broadcastable. Because a `Pair`, in our case, `','=>'.'`, is not treated as broadcastable we have to wrap it in a one-element container that is broadcastable.

The first approach was to wrap it in a one element array using `[` and `]` which is a bit inefficient, because it allocates a new temporary array.

You can use a one element tuple for this wrapping it in `(` and `,)` (note the comma before `)`, without it the pattern will not work correctly). This approach will not allocate memory.

Finally you can use an in-built `Ref` function, which will create an object of type `Base.RefValue{Pair{Char,Char}}` in this case that is seen by Julia as a 0-dimensional one element container (this is a bit more advanced topic that you can start exploring in [this section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/c/#Core.Ref) of the Julia manual). This approach also will not allocate memory.

Over what you can broadcast is described [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/arrays/#Broadcast-and-vectorization-1) in the Julia manual.

### Additional cases:

*Array of strings and missings*

For this you need latest Missings.jl (run `up` command in the package manager):

```
julia> s = ["2.2", "3.3", "4.4", missing]
4-element Array{Union{Missing, String},1}:
 "2.2"
 "3.3"
 "4.4"
 missing

julia> passmissing(parse).(Float64, s)
4-element Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}:
 2.2
 3.3
 4.4
  missing
```

*Array of string and `NaN`*

This should not happen in practice as you are missing strings and floats in one vector, but you can do this like this (I have added `5.5` to the vector to show you that the solution is not `NaN` specific but in general can ingest any string or any `Float64`):

```
julia> s = ["2.2", "3.3", "4.4", NaN, 5.5]
5-element Array{Any,1}:
    "2.2"
    "3.3"
    "4.4"
 NaN
   5.5

julia> [v isa Float64 ? v : parse(Float64, v) for v in s]
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
   2.2
   3.3
   4.4
 NaN
   5.5
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BogumiłKamiński for the very clear answer. Actually, I just got try that on my real problem: on a Dataframe, I have a column of the type `s = ["2.2", "3.3", "4.4", missing]`. Is there a way to convert that string `s` as a `Float64` (and would it be the same answer if i had `s = ["2.2", "3.3", "4.4", NaN]`)?

Comment: I have added examples how to handle these cases to the answer.

Comment: Many thanks @BogumiłKamiński. The example with `NaN` works perfectly, however, after having installed `Missings` typing `using Missings` and then `s = ["2.2", "3.3", "4.4", missing]` and `passmissing(parse).(Float64, s)`, I get `UndefVarError: passmissing not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0`

Comment: Very minor nitpick: Isn't it better to wrap the replace pair in `replace.(s, [','=>'.'])` in a `Ref` or a tuple, instead of allocating a vector? While the performance difference is slight, I believe using `Ref` is the normal recommendation.

Comment: @DNF - this is correct as `Ref` and tuple will not allocate, but my experience with teaching Julia is tat `[x]` is easier to understand for people just starting to learn it, because they can reuse the knowledge they already have. When using a tuple you need to explain that you have to put a comma after the expression you want to wrap and if you introduce `Ref` you should explain what `Base.RefValue{T}` is and how it works. I will add the two options to the answer.

Comment: I can understand that. Though tuples should be introduced as soon as possible, since they show up all over the place.

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother you guys with a probably very trivial question, but, do you have any idea why I get this error message when trying to use `passmissing` from the `Missings` package mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: What error do you get. Please make sure that you have Missings.jl version 0.4.0 installed, see the release notes https://github.com/JuliaData/Missings.jl/releases.

Comment: So I enter the command `Pkg.add("Missings") as well as `Pkg.clone("https://github.com/JuliaData/Missings.jl")`. But when I type `Pkg.installed()`, I get "Missings"   => v"0.3.1+". I saw that you just add `passmissing` 12 days ago in version 0.4.0, but it seems that I can't have it installed on my machine and I'm stuck with 0.3.1+. Again the solution is probably trivial but I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: use `Pkg.update()` function or simply press `]` in REPL and write `up` and enter. This will update all packages you have installed to their latest versions.

Comment: Just did both method that you described (`Pkg.update()` (which I had used previously) and `]` and `up` and enter). Unfortunately I still get `"Missings"   => v"0.3.1+"` though

Comment: But now `using Missings` and then `passmissing(parse).(Float64, s)` works (although I still get the version `Missings" => v"0.3.1+`). I don't know what went wrong. Many thanks for your time and your time @Bogumił Kamiński and sorry for the trouble

Comment: You probably have checked out a commit of Missings.jl repository earlier that was not tagged. That is what the + means (you probably checked out master which will be denoted as `#master` after the `+`). Using `free` command should make Julia track only tagged version for this repository. You might want to read https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/Pkg/ to learn the details.